# ionic 2 - calling pages functions from app.component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an ionic 2 appliction containing a menu and every time I select one item from the menu the main page should be updated, for that I wrote a function in my `main.ts` that returns the wanted result as a list , and in `app.component.ts` I have to call that function to be executed ..

What should I do please ??

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do I unsderstand your question correctly, how can you fire your function in main.ts from app.components.ts?

You could use [Ionic2 Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/) for this purpose:

In app.components.ts:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(public events: Events) {
}

clickMenu(item) {
events.publish('menu:clicked', item);
}
```

Add clickMenu(item) to your menu-item: (click)="clickMenu('whateverYouWantToPass')"

and in main.ts:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events) {
events.subscribe('menu:clicked', (item) => {
  // Do something with the clicked item data, e.g.:
  console.log(item[0]);
});
}
```

I hope this brings you closer to your solution.

Comment: Thank u sooo match :) u saved my life